# Xperia V New SD Card, can't make it recognize it as external

Tags: sd-card, sony-xperia-neo-v

SEARCHED FIRST, WANT TO ASK MYSELF!

So I just bought a new Micro SDHC card, 32gb Samsung, placed it in the turned off phone, then turned it on, the sd card is recognized, but it doesn't appear in the Applciations directory in Settings as External Memory, and if I try to move some app to external memory, it only appears as Move to INternal memory, and if I click it it changes to Move to Phone.
With Root Explorer there are 2 sdcard folders, sdcard and sdcard1, also a folder storage which contains sdcard0, sdcard1 and usbdisk.
What can I do to make the phone recognize the sd card completely and not use emulated sd card anymore?

Comment: Is your OS rooted?

Comment: yes, it is rooted

Comment: Stock ROM -- or custom ROM? Many stock roms do not support moving apps to the external sdcard. Still, your card should be included with the device's *Storage* settings.

Comment: Stock JB rom, I mean is it possible like it was on my last phone with ICS, to just be able to install the apps on the sd card? Or in JB is different